Flutter Validation Bug with Text editing controller
I am using the flutter form in that i am using the text editing controller for calling api and fill The data come from the api to controller but by doing this when I calling the form state .reset it is not working and also when the clearing the textediting controller validation also fires
please help me with this.
I am calling the api and set the value to controller and when  the radio button changes I want that my form is clear but reset is not working and also clearing the controller fires the validation
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final _kinFormKey = Form.of(context);
    final createFinanceApplicationCubit =
        context.read<FinanceApplicationCubit>();
    return BlocListener<FinanceApplicationCubit, FinanceApplicationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is FinanceApplicationInitialState) {
          EasyLoading.show();
        } else if (state is GetNextOfKinInfoDataSuccessState) {
          EasyLoading.dismiss();
          if (state.getUserNextOfKinModel.result?.items != null &&
              state.getUserNextOfKinModel.result?.items?.isNotEmpty == true) {
            NextKinInfoItem? data =
                state.getUserNextOfKinModel.result?.items?.first;

            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinTitleSelection =
                TitlesExtension.fromString(data?.title ?? "");
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinNameCtr.text =
                data?.fullName ?? '';

            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderCtr.text = data?.sex ?? "";
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderSelection =
                SexExtension.fromString(data?.sex ?? "");

            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinDOBCtr.text =
                data?.dateOfBirth ?? "";
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinRelationCtr.text =
                data?.relationship ?? "";
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinNewIcNoCtr.text =
                data?.nationalId ?? '';
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinPhoneCtr.text =
                data?.phoneNumber ?? "";

            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinHomePhoneCtr.text =
                data?.homePhoneNumber ?? "";
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinPersonalEmailCtr.text =
                data?.emailAddress ?? '';
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinRACtr.text =
                data?.houseAddress ?? "";
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinCityCtr.text =
                data?.houseCity ?? '';
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinStateCtr.text =
                data?.houseState ?? "";
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinPostCodeCtr.text =
                data?.housePostalCode ?? '';
          } else {
            print('response is null');
          }
        } else if (state is FormSubmissionSuccessState) {
          EasyLoading.dismiss();
          context.showFlash(
              barrierDismissible: false,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 6),
              builder: (context, controller) => CustomFlashBar(
                    controller: controller,
                    message: state.msg,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0XFF48a047),
                  ));
          createFinanceApplicationCubit
              .updateStep(createFinanceApplicationCubit.activeStep + 1);
        } else if (state is FormSubmissionUpdateState) {
          EasyLoading.dismiss();
          context.showFlash(
              barrierDismissible: false,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 6),
              builder: (context, controller) => CustomFlashBar(
                    controller: controller,
                    message: state.msg,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  ));
          createFinanceApplicationCubit
              .updateStep(createFinanceApplicationCubit.activeStep + 1);
        } else if (state is RadioOptionSelectedState) {
          if (state.msg == 'Spouse') {
            setState(() {
              _ignoreValidators = true;
              createFinanceApplicationCubit.updateKinInfo(
                  titleSelection:
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseTitleSelection ??
                          Titles.MR,
                  nameCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseFullNameCtr.text,
                  genderSelection:
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseGenderSelection ??
                          Sex.MALE,
                  genderCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseSexCtr.text,
                  newIcNoCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseNewIcCtr.text,
                  relationSelection: RelationShipExtension.toStringValue(
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseRelationSelection ??
                          RelationShip.HUSBAND),
                  relationCtr:
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseRelationshipCtr.text,
                  phoneCtr:
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseMobilePhoneCtr.text,
                  homePhoneCtr:
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseHomePhoneCtr.text,
                  personalEmailCtr:
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spousePersonalEmailCtr.text,
                  raCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit
                      .spouseResidentialAddressCtr.text,
                  dobCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseDOBCtr.text,
                  cityCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseCityCtr.text,
                  stateCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.spouseStateCtr.text,
                  postCodeCtr:
                      createFinanceApplicationCubit.spousePostCodeCtr.text);
              // _ignoreValidators = false;
            });
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderSelectionError = '';
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinTitleSelectionError = '';
          }
          if (state.msg == 'Family Reference') {
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.updateKinInfo(
                titleSelection:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceTitleSelection ??
                        Titles.MR,
                nameCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceNameCtr.text,
                genderSelection:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceGenderSelection ??
                        Sex.MALE,
                genderCtr:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceGenderCtr.text,
                newIcNoCtr:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceNewIcNoCtr.text,
                relationSelection:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceRelationCtr.text,
                relationCtr:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceRelationCtr.text,
                phoneCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.referencePhoneCtr.text,
                homePhoneCtr:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceHomePhoneCtr.text,
                personalEmailCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit
                    .referencePersonalEmailCtr.text,
                dobCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceDOBCtr.text,
                raCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceRACtr.text,
                cityCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceCityCtr.text,
                stateCtr: createFinanceApplicationCubit.referenceStateCtr.text,
                postCodeCtr:
                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.referencePostCodeCtr.text);
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderSelectionError = '';
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinTitleSelectionError = '';
          }
          if (state.msg == 'Other') {
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinTitleSelection = Titles.MR;
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinNameCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderSelection = null;
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinNewIcNoCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinRelationCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinDOBCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinRelationCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinPhoneCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinHomePhoneCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinPersonalEmailCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinRACtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinCityCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinStateCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinPostCodeCtr.clear();
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderSelectionError =
                S.of(context).kinInfo_SelectSex;
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinTitleSelectionError =
                S.of(context).kinInfo_selectTitle;
            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinTitleSelection = null;
          }
        } else if (state is FormSubmissionFailedState) {
          EasyLoading.showInfo(state.errorMsg);
        }
      },
child: BlocBuilder<FinanceApplicationCubit, FinanceApplicationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Form(
            key: _kinFormKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        AppSpacer.p16(),
                        //// Details of Next of kin fields
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: TabViewTextWidget(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.shadow,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            text: S.of(context).kinInfo_detailsOfNextKin,
                          ),
                        ),

                        if (createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                    .getUserNextOfKinModel.result?.items ==
                                [] ||
                            createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinID == null ||
                            (createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinID == '')) ...[
                          AppSpacer.p16(),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 35,
                            child: ListView.separated(
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return AppSpacer.p8();
                              },
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount:
                                  createFinanceApplicationCubit.options.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                final option = createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                    .options[index];

                                return CustomRadioButton(
                                  value: option,
                                  groupValue: createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                      .selectedOption,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                        .onRadioButtonChanged(value);
                                  },
                                  label: option,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                        AppSpacer.p16(),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                           
                            AppSpacer.p12(),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: AppTextFieldWithLabel(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                                labelText: '${S.of(context).kinInfo_name} *',
                                validator: (value) {
                                  print(
                                      "ignore validator inside the filed ${_ignoreValidators}");
                                  if (_ignoreValidators) {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return S.of(context).kinInfo_enterName;
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                textEditingController:
                                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinNameCtr,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _ignoreValidators = false;
                                  });
                                },
                                autoValidate:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        AppSpacer.p16(),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: AppTextFieldWithLabel(
                                errorWidget: commonError(
                                    errorText: createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                            .kinGenderSelectionError ??
                                        '',
                                    context: context),
                                labelText: '${S.of(context).kinInfo_Sex} *',
                                textEditingController:
                                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinGenderCtr,
                                enabled: false,
                                suffix: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                errorText: createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                    .kinGenderSelectionError,
                                onTap: () {
                                  selectionDialog<Sex>(
                                    context: context,
                                    title: '${S.of(context).kinInfo_SelectSex}',
                                    values: Sex.values,
                                    selectedValue: createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                        .kinGenderSelection,
                                    onSelected: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                            .kinGenderSelection = value;
                                        createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                            .kinGenderCtr.text = value.name;
                                        createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                            .kinGenderSelectionError = null;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: AppTextFieldWithLabel(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textEditingController:
                                    createFinanceApplicationCubit.kinNewIcNoCtr,
                                labelText: '${S.of(context).kinInfo_IcNo} *',
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (_ignoreValidators) {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return S.of(context).kinInfo_enterIcNo;
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _ignoreValidators = false;
                                  });
                                },
                                autoValidate:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AppSpacer.p12(),
                            Expanded(
                              child: AppTextFieldWithLabel(
                                autoValidate:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                labelText:
                                    '${S.of(context).kinInfo_relationship} *',
                                textEditingController:
                                    createFinanceApplicationCubit
                                        .kinRelationCtr,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return S.of(context).kinInfo_enterRelation;
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                    AppSpacer.p16(),

in this i want when the radio button clickes if there is data for that then fill other wise clear the form but is not working
Give solution for this
